# Closing nested accordion closes everything

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my nested accordions.
I have been trying to figure out how to nest my accordions but in a sense that I dont need to write any extra jquery codes for each specific one I add.

I made a jsfiddle as an example... https://jsfiddle.net/L2bwmgL8/

and the code for the accordion looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function close_accordion_section() {
    $('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
    $('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(1000).removeClass('open');
  }

  $('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
    // Grab current anchor value
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).closest('.accordion-section-title');
    //console.log(currentAttrValue);
    if (currentAttrValue.hasClass('active')) {
      close_accordion_section();
    } else {
      close_accordion_section();

      // Add active class to section title
      currentAttrValue.addClass('active');
      // Open up the hidden content panel
      $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue.attr('href')).slideDown(1000).addClass('open');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(currentAttrValue.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1000);
      }, 1001);
      //console.log((currentAttrValue.attr('href')));
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

This way it works fine when I dont have them nested. However, when they are nested as in the example, under the first accordion (ignore the broken images).
Then when I click on the specific accordion to close, everything inside that accordion closes, including the parent one. Or, maybe I think just the parent closes.

Now, I tried, maybe passing the `currentAttrValue` inside the `close_accordion_section()` function like `close_accordion_section(currentAttrValue)` and changing the `close_acordion_section` to:

```
function close_accordion_section() {
    $(this).closest('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
    $(this).closest('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(1000).removeClass('open');
}
```

But then everything opens up nicely, but I cant close any of the accordions anymore.

Any help and explanation would be appriciated, I am still learning the ropes so to speak.

Comment: I could easily be wrong, but doesn't close_accordion_section cease to exist as soon as the ready() function returns?  That might be contributing.  Try moving it above the ready() function so it's globally scoped

Comment: Ok, so it's probably fine since jQuery is theoretically hanging onto references to it.  Just not a comfortable piece of code.

Comment: Yeah, i know @Tibrogargan. I was trying to make it work, so it was kinda left like that for the time being..

Comment: It's probably just me but it's giving me the heebie jeebies.  Theoretically the name "close_accordion_section" is still in scope for your click() function since that is defined at the same level as the close_accordion_section function so it's probably perfectly ok.

Comment: Well, im still learning, so i will look out for things like that in the future. Adeneo, below gave a very nice example how simple it can be...wanted to slap myself for overcomplicating things..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simplify it, and then just target the siblings of the current accordion so as to not affect the parent accordion of nested accordions etc.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.accordion-section-title').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var self     = $(this).toggleClass('active');
        var section  = self.closest('.accordion-section');
        var siblings = section.siblings('.accordion-section');

        siblings.find('.accordion-section-content').slideUp(1000).removeClass('open').end()
                .find('.accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');

        $('.accordion ' + self.attr('href')).slideToggle(1000).toggleClass('open')
                                            .find('.accordion-section-title.active')
                                            .trigger('click');


        if (self.hasClass('active')) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $(self.attr('href')).offset().top
                }, 1000);
            }, 1001);
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/L2bwmgL8/2/)

Comment: Wow, im baffled...how in the world did you manage to come up with a solution in a matter of minutes..Im going through the code and i do understand it, i just dont think i would come up with something so simple and clean like this.. I still have a lot to learn

Comment: And thanks for the help. I'll look into your code some more to understand all of it and marking yours as the answer. I have only one question. What if i want to close the open children of the parent accordion when it closes? @adeneo

Comment: @IvanHorvatin - Thank you for the kind words 8-) ... closing the children of an accordion when it closes could be done with something like `...find('.accordion-section-title.active').trigger('click');`, where one finds any active accordions inside the current content, and then closes them. I've added this to the answer as well.

Comment: Thanks once more for help. It really works like a charm, i'm playing a bit with it still, but seriously thanks a ton! @adeneo

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your if else statement:

you need to cut one of the calls to close_accordion_section():

I have a problem with my nested accordions. I have been trying to figure out how to nest my accordions but in a sense that I dont need to write any extra jquery codes for each specific one I add.

I made a jsfiddle as an example... https://jsfiddle.net/L2bwmgL8/

and the code for the accordion looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function close_accordion_section() {
    $('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
    $('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(1000).removeClass('open');
  }

  $('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
    // Grab current anchor value
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).closest('.accordion-section-title');
    //console.log(currentAttrValue);
    if (currentAttrValue.hasClass('active')) {
      close_accordion_section();
    } else {
      //CUT THIS

      // Add active class to section title
      currentAttrValue.addClass('active');
      // Open up the hidden content panel
      $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue.attr('href')).slideDown(1000).addClass('open');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(currentAttrValue.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1000);
      }, 1001);
      //console.log((currentAttrValue.attr('href')));
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kjyqmzuh/